# How to access Windows Certificate Store from Internet Explorer?

Tags: security

I have an intranet web application where I need to sign PDF documents which live on the server side. The signer has to be the end user who is currently issuing the sign command from a given web page, and his digital signature/certificate is located in his Smart Card.

From what I have gathered, when a user plugs his smart card into the reader, the information is populated to Windows Key Store. Am I right? So what I need to do is to somehow read that information off Windows Certificate Store from Internet Explorer. I know javascript doesn't reach that information. I also know that java can do it, but if I can avoid using a java applet, I would.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### **Its not possible to do so.**

If you want to sign document, the browser would have to send a certificate containing the private key to the server. If you could access the Windows Certificate Store through the browser, that would be a critial security issue, since an attacker could read all the certifiates private keys.

**Another thing I'd suggest based on the basic idea you're describing**

Build a secure authentication system where the users can sign into the intranet app using forms or windows authentication.

Hold a certificate for each user on the server side. If the user then uploads the PDF sign it using the users certificate and offer it to be downloaded.

**Please think of having a local app**

If the user has a SmartCard locally, why not having a local application signing the PDF? See you've got all you need and want locally. Why push it to the server side?

Answer (score 0):

How often does the signing occur?  Perhaps consider using a Java Web start app (sort of a compromise - depending on your security policies) to do the signing?

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the possibilities offered by ASSP there? 
It is worth a try.

Comment: What's that? Explain, please.